# How to pass variable to function that may or may not be available based upon options?

Tags: javascript, clean-code

I have a question and it is quite simple. Here are the details:

- I want to pass an options object into my `mainFunction` and some other functions inside of it, i.e. `someFunctionCall` and `anotherFunctionCall`. This `options` object is very much for configs. Because my algorithm has many different settings, I am much better off passing the whole object rather than certain properties.
- Additionally, within my `mainFunction`, I compute and assign to a variable (`hardToComputeThing`). This computation is computationally intensive. So when my config states that it doesn't need it for the whole of `mainFunction` then we shouldn't use it.

The tricky part is when I use my internal function, like `someFunctionCall`. Assuming that `someBool=false`(from `options`), which means that `hardToComputeThing=null`. I am passing some empty variable inside each object and depending on my config object (`options`) to inform each internal function on whether I should use that empty object or not. I know it seems a little funky, but the great thing I love about using `options` is that I can still make use of other keys in `options` and it makes explicit what my current config is.

So my question is: **Is this good practice? If not, than what should I do?** Is it better to pass `{x,y,hardToComputeThing}` as a functional argument and handle for the missingness of `hardToComputeThing`, e.g. `banana= (hardToComputeThing)? hardToComputeThing[0]*f(apple): f(apple)`?

Below is a some pseudocode to illustrate my problem.

```
const mainFunction = ( x, options) = {

  const {someBool} = options

  const hardToComputeThing = (someBool)? computeTheThing(): null

  someFunctionCall(x,y,hardToComputeThing, options)

  anotherFunctionCall(z,hardToComputeThing, options)

}

const someFunctionCall = (x,y,hardToComputeThing,options)=>{
  const {someBool} = options


  let banana;
  if(someBool){
    banana = hardToComputeThing[0]* f(apple)
    ... // Some big piece of code
  }else{
    banana = f(apple)
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is "funky" at all - I do similar all the time (in Javascript,).  Either way is fine, whatever feels best to you.  Rik also has a nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting hardToComputeThing to null when someBool is false, you could give hardToComputeThing a default implementation which doesn't do anything. That way you can pass the hardToComputeThing to the other functions who can use it without additional null checks.

This pattern is known as the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

Comment: In the OPs example code, returning `[1]` works perfectly as a "null object".  In real code it might be harder.  Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use lazy evaluation: You compute the `hardToComputeThing` if and when it is needed (and, probably, you cache the value, then, in case it is needed, again):

```
const mainFunction = ( x, options) = {
  let hardToComputeThing = {
     cachedValue: null,
     get: function() {
       if (this.cachedValue === null) this.cachedValue = computeTheThing();
       return this.cachedValue;
     }
  }
  someFunctionCall(x,y,hardToComputeThing, options)
  anotherFunctionCall(z,hardToComputeThing, options)
}

const someFunctionCall = (x,y,hardToComputeThing,options)=>{
  if(whateverCondition){
    let banana = hardToComputeThing.get()[0]* f(apple);
    ... // Some big piece of code
  } else {
    banana = f(apple)
  }
}
```

The main advantage is that you will not need to duplicate the logic for `whateverCondition` (which, I assume, might be non-trivial). The other answer, by Rik D, has the same advantage, but keeps the logic for `whateverCondition` in `mainFunction()` while my answer would move it to `someFunctionCall()`. No idea what would be more natural/convenient in your use case.